# Hidden service won't connect

Tags: configuration, server

I recently created a hidden service to host a personal site of mine. It runs Ubuntu with nginx as webserver.... last night it was working perfectly, yet today it refuses to connect to the hidden service. I'm not sure why this is, as both Nginx and Tor are running with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need synchronized clocks on tor. It is usually problem when computer goes to sleep. Restarting tor after waking up helps.

Comment: Kolar I don't know why that would be a problem- I pay for hosting on a completely different server that isn't put to sleep.

Comment: Another reason why tor hidden service becomes inaccessible is that each day it is registered in 6 relays with HSDir flags. If all 6 relays gets restarted the same day then hidden service is inaccessible for rest of the day. It happend to me occasionally. Restarting tor helps, it will re-register hidden service.

Comment: Radim- I've tried restarting Tor at least ten times, and i've tried reinstalling Nginx. Nginx and Tor are running without error messages in the logs, so I honestly don't know what else to try.